# Can you change from a J1 visa to an ESTA by going to Mexico for a few weeks?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, uk-citizens, j1-visas

I'm a UK National currently on a J1 visa as a student in the US which expires on July 13th (after the grace period) but my flight isn't booked until August 22nd as I want to do some more travelling around the US. Can I go to Mexico for around 10 days and then re-enter the US on an ESTA?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What's your citizenship?

Comment: I'm a British Student

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have your ESTA approved you should not have an issue.  [As per CBP you're not a subject to the 2 year home rule](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/study-exchange/student/residency-waiver/eligibility.html) as long as you're not entering the US for the purpose of work or study.

So if you leave the country and then enter on an approved [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) you should not have an issue.